Graph of function as separable topological space
In 'Martin's Axiom implies a stronger version of Blumberg's Theorem' by Stewart Baldwin there is a function $f: X\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $X$ is a categorically dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with every element $f$-pleasant and $X\cap\mathbb{Q}=\emptyset$.
In page 70 the author says that there is a set $X_0\subseteq X$ for wich the set $\{(x,f(x)):x\in X_0\}$ is countable dense in $\Gamma(f)$, where $\Gamma(f)$ is the graph of $f$.
How can i construct $X_0$?
Ps. I know that if $U$ is any open subset of the plane intersecting $\Gamma(f)$, then
$\lvert U\cap \Gamma(f)\rvert>\aleph_0$.

Either I'm missing something, or this is basic topology: $\Gamma(f)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so it is separable.
